# Can I do basic math within a mongo update using properties of the object?

Tags: mongodb

In SQL you can do something like:

```
UPDATE test SET a = b + c
```

I am wondering if there is something I can do that is similar in MongoDB.  For example something like:

```
db.test.update({},{$set: {a: b + c}})
```

However, when I try that it says b and c are not defined (which makes sense).  Is there some way I can tell mongo to use the value of fields of the object it is updating?  Or do I always need to do it in two steps--first retrieving the fields and then using them to construct the appropriate update statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do that with MongoDB in an update operation. You would need to use something like a [map/reduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce) or [db.eval](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution#Server-sideCodeExecution-Using%7B%7Bdb.eval%28%29%7D%7D) to accomplish it and even then you're still going to be technically running two queries, one to find and one to update.

Comment: Ok that's what I thought but figured it was worth a shot to see if the fine folks on SO had any cool ideas :-P

Answer (score 1):

This is a decade later but.. It was on me way and I kept your post for when I solved it.

You can, if you do the maths before the insertion to DB, pull value from DB translate to number, do the maths and add new variable to insertOne or updateOne...

Either way.. You can.